# R - How to work with large dataset that does not (but could) fit within memory?

Tags: r

I am trying to work with some data, and it is brutally large (genetic data). With only using the bare minimum amount of columns I need, I am still looking at **~30GB** of data.

Assuming I upgrade my PC to have 64GB of RAM, would I even be able to work with that data in R, or will I run into issues somewhere else? I.e., CPU not being beefy enough (AMD Ryzen 3600X), RStudio not being able to handle it, etc.

If RStudio will not be able to handle it or will be extremely slow, is there another way I can work with this data? I just want to do dimension reduction (which may make it a lot easier for me to use R) and run logistic regression on the data, maybe with some varied train/test splits.

Any help here is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: To work with a dataset that does not fit in memory, you can use the R package ff : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ff/index.html

Comment: Look into the `arrow` or `duckdb` packages for strong performance with larger than memory data. for example: https://hbs-rcs.github.io/large_data_in_R/#efficiently-query-taxi-data-with-duckdb